# Symfony doesn't validate on iphone

Tags: android, iphone, symfony

I have set an entity with this code

```
/**
 * @Assert\Length(
 *      min = 20,
 *      max = 2000,
 *      minMessage = "message.min_length",
 *      maxMessage = "message.max_length"
 * )
 */
protected $message;
```

When I'm using a desktop navigator it refuses to send when the message is less than 20, but when on iphone or tablet (android) the message is sent, even empty. The field is a textarea.
Any ideas ?

Comment: Please show the code that you use to validate your object.

Comment: There is no code. For me the validation id done via the @Assert and Symfony mechanisms, no?

Comment: Well, the question is whether you ever call the validator (for example, through `$form->isValid()`) or if you simply rely on client-side validation.

Comment: Of course not I don't rely on client validation ;-) I use if($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) { and I can see it works on my desktop navigator. When the field is empty, I receive the message from the navigator, when I set 1 character it sends and then I receive the message from the server side. Excepts on tablets, iphone...

Comment: I'm afraid the only thing you can do is to debug what data the `Length` constraint is getting pass (and if it is even called at all). At least, there is no special handling built in the Symfony Validator component that explains this behaviour.

Comment: Thanks, that's where I came too. Wanted to know if it was only me... Know I have to find a way to debug on a smartphone...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:**

According to the symfony documentation, assert length assumes NULL & empty strings as valid, hence why it passes (http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Length.html#min).

Please add Assert\NotBlank() and this will validate the empty strings

--

What the symfony form builder will do is add the form validation options to the form elements, for example:

```
<input name="my_field" required>
```

A desktop browser will validate that this form element is required (client side) & if empty, prevent the form being submitted. On mobile devices, they do not validate the forms automatically (I'm still to find a reason for this..?), so you will need to add some javascript form validation to prevent the form from submitted if it's invalid on mobile/tablet devices.

Please make sure that your form is mapped to the entity class correctly:

```
// AppBundle/Form/EntityForm.php

<?php

namespace AppBundle\Form;

class EntityForm extends AbstractType
{
    // ...

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\MyEntity',
        ]);
    }
}
```

To ensure symfony validates annotations, please add this to your app/config/config.yml

```
# app/config/config.yml
framework:
    validation: { enable_annotations: true }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but the "Assert" is not supposed to do the validation from server side ? So going back to the user if the validation is not good ?

Comment: Could you provide us with some code examples from your codebase so that we can see what has been done so far please?

Comment: Yes what code do you need ? I have just followed the cookbook and symfony rules, and the validation (server) works from desktop navigator

Comment: Form, Controller (if that is where ->isValid() is called), Entity

Comment: Yes it is called, I use if($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()). I had another try with my smartphone, and in fact the validation works when there is less than 20 characters but more than zero. So for me the Assert\Length was including NotBlank but it doesn't seem. And I can't see this problem with my desktop navigator as it uses its validation... So I need to add NotBlank ? or is it a "bug" with Length ?